# Need to start batch processing in firebase functions after API call

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, batch-processing

I have written a firebase function API call.

Now, when I call this API it should return a response as {status: 200, message: 'In progress'} and batch processing should start at the server end.

But after processing a few records I receive an error

Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Need to process more than 100+ records.

Currently, my code looks like

```
app.post('/writeBatchData', async (req, res) => {
  writeBatchData(req.body);
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    message: 'In Progress'
  });
});



const writeBatchData = async recordDetails => {
      for (let count = 0; count < recordDetails.length; count++) {
        let recordInformation = recordDetails[count];
        const recordInfo = await writeDataOnDatabase(recordInformation);
        // db operation
      }
      return 'success';
};

async function writeDataOnDatabase(recordInfo) {
  try {
    // write data on database
  }
  catch(error) {

  }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this??

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Hello, you need to add to your question the **entire** code of your function (I guess it is an HTTPS Cloud Function).

Comment: Please check the code above

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was by default the timeout for firebase is one minute for both frontend and backend service; So whatever the number of records processed in one minute is processed

Currently, the workaround I have used is I have increased the timeout to 540 seconds i.e 9 minutes (which is max in firebase). So I am able to process more records.

But this is not the final solution

So if anyone is having a better solution, please comment